# SQL Column Value Within string

Tags: sql, function, matching

I Have a string below

```
100Pipers22WoodfieldRoadBlackpoolFY16AX
```

I also have an address table on where i want to cross reference the postcode column to see if the value exists in the above string. Column value would be FY16AX which is visible in the string.

I cant seem to get a match.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide the code you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @vString nvarchar(50)
Set @vString = '100Pipers22WoodfieldRoadBlackpoolFY16AX'

Select Count(*) From tbl_Address Where Zip = right(@vString,6)
```

If the select statement returns a value greater than zero, you have a match.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `like`.  In standard SQL, this would look like:

```
where string like '%' || postcode
```

The `||` is the string concatenation operator.  Some databases have their own operators or functions for this functionality.

Comment: Might want to consider case too - e.g. `UPPER` or `LOWER` on both your string and search-term (in this case `postcode`)

Comment: @doublesidedstickytape, better to use a case insensitive collation.